# Create another terminal box in ssh

Tags: kali-linux

So lets say i just connect my A pc to B pc using ssh.both the os is kali linux.i type "airmon-ng start wlan0"on pc A,then pc B is start those command.but why when i type that command,the terminal box is not showing in pc B? How to show it?

Answer (score 1):

Install `screen` on both systems.  Connect via ssh, start a screen session.   On the other box, open a terminal and run `screen -x`.

There are other utils like [sniffy](http://sniffy.sourceforge.net/) which may also do what you want, but if you don't need to be sneaky about it then using `screen` works great AND has other benefits like having multiple terminals via one ssh session and being able to disconnect from them leaving process(es) running and being able to reconnect even from a different ssh session.